# What are the contents of an Ubuntu bootable USB?

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb

When you make an Ubuntu bootable USB (or CD) what files and folders are created on the USB?

Just the things created in the root of the USB (not inside those folders).

A brief explanation of each item would be nice.

<sup>*One of the reasons for such question is that I had a bootable usb stick with lots of other files which got mixed with the installation files so I want to filter out my files. The explanation of the items is for curiousity. NVM anyways :)*</sup>

Comment: Just download the iso file from ubuntu.com and mount or extract it. It's exactly the same after writing the iso to a USB or DVD.

Comment: Mounting an iso is a nice idea *which didn't occur to my mind actually*. thx XD ...but creating a usb, I have to find one and I have to intend to format it and it takes time. thx anyway :) @WinEunuuchs2Unix if you think of it as a homework assignment just don't answer it. someone else might think it's a cool discussion topic. I "did my homework" before asking. I googled for like 5 minutes (which I thought is enough). I just get "how to make usb", nothing about the contents. Also in the help centre it says that any question not mentioned in AU and isn't a "bad question" is great to be asked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list file in Ubuntu iso archive lists all files included in an iso

- http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.list

And the manifest file lists all files included in the live image
i.e. filesystem.squashfs file.

- http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-i386.manifest

The Ubuntu bootable USB is essentially these files when created by usb-creator of Ubuntu.

Comment: Link to the file list is broken

Answer (score 1):

When you make a bootable Ubuntu live USB these files and folders are created on the root of the USB.

[image]
<sup>**Ubuntu 16.04 live USB**</sup>